# not getting integer values stored in viewbag on view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have list of integer values in my **view bag**

```
 List<int> ChkOptions = {1,2,3,4.......}

 for (int i = 0; i < ChkOptions.Count(); i++)
 {
  ViewBag.ChkOptions = ChkOptions.ElementAt(i);
  }
```

Now i want to take this **viewbag value** on my **view page**.

this is what i am doing on my **view page** but it it throwing me error on dis line:

```
 var chk = (List<int>)ViewBag.ChkOptions;
```

**Cannot convert type 'int' to System.Collections.Generic.List**

can any one tell me how do i take all this **integer values from viewbag** on my **view** in **var** variable??

Comment: try ViewBag.ChkOptions as List<int>

Comment: In your for-loop you reset your `ViewBag.ChkOptions` everytime..? So its just one `int` that gets overwritten everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work :-

Controller :-

```
 List<int> ChkOptions = {1,2,3,4.......}

 ViewBag.ChkOptions = ChkOptions;
```

View :-

```
var chk=ViewBag.ChkOptions as List<int>;
```

Or use foreach to traverse your List as :

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.ChkOptions as List<int>)
{...}
```

Comment: i hv tried it but m gettin perfect values at controller side but null values at view side

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, you overwrite the `ViewBag.ChkOptions` everytime with a new int:

This is what you're doing:

```
List<int> ChkOptions = {1,2,3,4.......}

for (int i = 0; i < ChkOptions.Count(); i++)
{
    var elem = ChkOptions.ElementAt(i); // gives an int
    ViewBag.ChkOptions = elem; // ViewBag.ChkOptions = int
}
```

Just remove the for-loop:

```
List<int> ChkOptions = {1,2,3,4.......}
ViewBag.ChkOptions = ChkOptions;
```

Then its available in the View like you're doing:

```
var chk = (List<int>)ViewBag.ChkOptions;
```